# Getting my express backend to make conditional api calls

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

Can anyone help.
I have built a webpage in react using the api from newsapi.org. The webpage conditionally calls the api depending on what is selected in the web page. The api calls have been structured as follows:

```
const baseUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v2";

export const getNews = (path) => {

  const link = `${baseUrl}/top-headlines?sources=${path}&apiKey=${process.env.react_app_api_key}`;

  return axios.get(link);
};
```

and

```
export const getSearchNews = (searchTerm, sources) => {
  let link = "";
  if (sources) {
    link = `${baseUrl}/everything?q=${searchTerm}&sources=${sources}&apiKey=${process.env.react_app_api_key}`;
  } else {
    link = `${baseUrl}/everything?q=${searchTerm}&apiKey=${process.env.react_app_api_key}`;
  }
  return axios.get(link);
};
```

My question is, how do i get express to make these requests instead? I need to make this change because newsApi no longer allow requests direct from the client but they can from a backend server (apparently)

(response from another stack-overflow post: You can't make requests from the browser anymore, you'll have to use a backend. I had the same problem and the easiest way around it was implementing a Node (Express) server. Source: [Error 426 from newsapi.org once I deployed my site on Netlify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62157026/error-426-from-newsapi-org-once-i-deployed-my-site-on-netlify))

I have done very little on the backend so far so this is really confusing me.

I've been googling and following this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJA9rDX7azM which gives me the basic idea but i'm struggling with how to do this for my particular use case.

Can anyone help, is this a simple thing or not?

Comment: All you need to do is create a route in your express server to handle these api calls and then mimic all of these calls. So you could do something like /newsapi/everything/... so that when your express server sees /newsapi/ it knows it needs to send the request to the old URL you already know about.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Please bear with me I don't know express and backend stuff so could I please clarify further. Do I put something like this and somehow get /newsapi/everything to point to api.js in the client files where the api logic is?


   app.get("/newsapi/everything", (req, res) => {
  request(
    "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=The key here",
    function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        
        // let parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
        res.send(body);

Comment: apologies, i can't get it to format my code correctly, basically: app.get("/newsapi/everything", (req, res) => ....

Comment: Yup. That looks like it would work.

Comment: Err, I still don't understand, how to i get "/newsapi/everything" in the express server code to point to api.js (which is one of the files in the client side)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what api.js is, I would recommend something like this:

NOTE: This requires a package for the outbound requests like 'bent' or 'axios'. I see you use axios on the frontend so I would use that on the backend to remove the learning curve. I don't use axios, so I'll form it like a fetch so it's easy to understand.

```js
app.route('/newsapi')
  .all((req,res,next) => {
    //Any auth method required
    next();
  })
  .get(async (req,res,next) => {
    const url = req.originalUrl.replace('/newsapi','')
    return fetch(`${news_api_host}${url}&apiKey=${stored_api_key}`)
  })
  .post(async (req,res,next) => {
    // whatever post API instructions you might have
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, api.js is just the file on the client side containing the code at the beginning of this thread.

Thanks for the code above i'll take a look and see if i can get it to work