# retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 426 Error displaying while calling news Api

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

i am calling the api in a right manner but still giving http 426 error here is the full error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.news_api_jetpack_compose, PID: 7437
                                                                                                    retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 426 
                                                                                                        at retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse(KotlinExtensions.kt:53)
                                                                                                        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:161)
                                                                                                        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@abdba2b, androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@9c38e88, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@2e15021, AndroidUiDispatcher@adf5c46]
2023-05-14 11:02:44.541  7437-7437  Process                 com...mple.news_api_jetpack_compose  I  Sending signal. PID: 7437 SIG: 9`

the api calling part
`object ApiClient {
    private const val BASE_URL="https://newsapi.org/v2/"
    private val retrofit=Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
    val newsApiService:NewsApiService= retrofit.create(NewsApiService::class.java)
}`

here is the query i have passed
`    var news by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<NewsArticle>()) }
    val apiKey="21f8e62d9e1c45b49af0a1e373cb619b"
    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = apiKey
    ){

            val response = ApiClient.newsApiService.getNews(
                query = "tesla",
                from = "2023-01-13",
                sortBy = "publishedAt",
                language = "in",
                apiKey = apiKey
            )
            news = response.articles



    }
    LazyColumn {
        itemsIndexed(news) { index,article ->
            NewsCard(article)
        }
    }
}
```

It was running perfectly one hour ago but after sometimes it start giving fatal exception retrofit http 426 error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 426 from newsapi.org once I deployed my site on Netlify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62157026/error-426-from-newsapi-org-once-i-deployed-my-site-on-netlify)