# How to resolve 'TypeError: e is undefined' error when hosting a React app on Netlify?

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, netlify

My react app is working in my local machine but when i deployed it on the netlify, it shows error "TypeError: e is undefined". I am very confused why is this error coming when there is no e variable in the code.

[image: Screenshot of the error in devtools]

This is my [GitHub Link of this project](https://github.com/midikaif/News-App).

First it was showing that this error is in header component so i comment it down but the error is still there.
i thought that maybe the comments are making problem so i removed the comments but nothing helped.

Here is the `Header` component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import HeaderCard from "./HeaderCard/HeaderCard";
import "./Header.css";
import SliderHeaderCard from "./SliderHeader/SliderHeaderCard";

export default class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    const { articles } = this.props;
    let settings = {
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      pauseOnHover: true
    }

    return (
      <>
        <section className="hero">
          <div className="container">
            {
              articles.filter((val, i) => i < 3).map((article, i) => <HeaderCard news={article} />)
            }
            <Slider {...settings} className="boxtmp">
              {
                articles.filter((val, i) => i > 2).map(article => <SliderHeaderCard news={article} />)
              }
            </Slider>

          </div>
        </section>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the `Home` component, which renders `Header`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Home.css";
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import HomeContent from "../HomeContent/HomeContent";
import Discover from "../Discover/Discover";
import Footer from "../Footer/Footer";
import NavHeader from "../NavHeader/NavHeader";

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      article: [],
      loading: false,
      page: 1,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {

    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=sports&apiKey=${this.props.apiKey}`;
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const parsedData = await data.json();
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      article: parsedData.articles,
      totalResults: parsedData.totalResults,
      page: 1,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <NavHeader/>
        <Header articles={this.state.article} />
        <HomeContent />
        <Discover />
        <Footer/>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could it be because of the failed request directly above that error to newsapi.org?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 426 from newsapi.org once I deployed my site on Netlify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62157026/error-426-from-newsapi-org-once-i-deployed-my-site-on-netlify)

Comment: Issue is with the API request (see linked question above), but also your app should have handling for failed API requests (e.g. by checking `data.ok`).

Comment: and you should probably ditch classes for components... such as boilerplate and not really used anymore. standards are arrow components. ik it does not solve ur issue but others already answered ur problem

Comment: So do i have to add backend to solve this problem?

Comment: @MdkaifKhan seems that way unless you can find another API. And I agree with Lith that you should be using functional components especially for new projects.